# How to deserialize json body with "0" in parameter

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm using a API that give me this json as a response,
This is json response body :

```
{
   "meta":{
      "status":200,
      "message":"success"
   },
   "data":{
      "0":{
         "MsgID":"2661689817",
         "Status":"6",
         "SendTime":"2021-10-3114:30:04",
         "DeliverTime":"2021-10-31 14:30:07"
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is `"0":{...` in this body.

How can I deserialize this into a Class.

it can't deserialize on `"string _0"` prop.

Comment: Is it always "0"?

Comment: This is more than likely a dictionary, deserialize it as such

Comment: @LIama : yes it's always "0"

Comment: What serializer are you using?

Comment: @Llama : newtonsoft.json

Comment: Please can you show your current C# class definiton for the above JSON?

Comment: Have you tried `JsonProperty` attribute. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar : no,I use it and tell u the result. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `JsonProperty`

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("0") ]
    public _0 _0 { get; set; }
}

public class _0
{
    public string MsgID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string SendTime { get; set; }
    public string DeliverTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the @TheGeneral says, this is like a dictionary. You can parse - like this:

```
public void ParseObject()
{
    var response = @"{
                       'meta':{
                          'status':200,
                          'message':'success'
                       },
                       'data':{
                          '0':{
                             'MsgID':'2661689817',
                             'Status':'6',
                             'SendTime':'2021-10-3114:30:04',
                             'DeliverTime':'2021-10-31 14:30:07'
                          }
                       }
                    }";

    var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MetaData>(response);
}

public class MetaData
{
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string SendTime { get; set; }
}
```